# Cannot convert from void to bool when trying to use an array in my reverse function

Tags: c#, arrays, reverse

Just as the heading states, I am trying to reverse a float array with my own reverse function.

The reverse function must not return a variable. The logic of the program may be off, so I am probably approaching this wrong.

Now the error I get is that it cannot convert from void to bool.

```
public static void reverse(float[] floatArr)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < floatArr.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(floatArr[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < floatArr.Length / 2; i++)
    {
        float tmp = floatArr[i];
        floatArr[i] = floatArr[floatArr.Length - i - 1];
        floatArr[floatArr.Length - i - 1] = tmp;
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    float[] floatArr = new float[5] { 5.6F, 6.4F, 4.2F, 3.6F, 8.4F };
    Console.WriteLine(reverse(floatArr)); // cannot convert from void to bool
}
```

I know that I could fix this by having the reverse function be a float function and thus returning a float, but question stated that it must not return a value.

Comment: `Array.Reverse(floatArr);`?

Comment: I need to create my own function.

Comment: [Reinventing the wheel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinventing_the_wheel)?

Comment: I knew there was a function to reverse it already. I was told to reinvent the wheel, as you say, for my homework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to print a function which returns type is void.

```
Console.WriteLine(reverse(floatArr)); // cannot convert from void to bool -> this is correct error
```

You should first call `reverse(floatArr)` and if the intention to print then you should loop on array to print the values. like as follows:

```
reverse(floatArr);
foreach(var val in floatArr)
{
    Console.WriteLine(val);
}
```

This will print the values in different lines on console. If you want to print all values in one line then use the below line (credit to @LeonidVasilyev)

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", floatArr));
```

Comment: [`string.Join(",", floatArr)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421(v=vs.110).aspx) is handy.

Comment: @LeonidVasilyev Would that not make the entire array a string?

Comment: @LeonidVasilyev - Thanks for the suggestion. Updated the answer.

Comment: @user1672994 thanks for adding it to the answer and explaining it.